# Issue with group/domain controls and admin rights

Tags: windows-xp, windows-server-2003, administrator, group-policy

Server: Windows Server 2003
PC: Windows XP (Laptop)
Issue: The PC in question cannot get administrator rights even when logged on as the top level administrator account, or any other admin account. The PC needs admin rights to install printers regularly, as well as various other hardware. I have created a custom user that has full admin rights.

Previously, this PC was only used via wireless, and was never a part of the domain, it was always just its own workgroup computer that was carried around our warehouse. It is now hooked up on a RJ-45 and will be stationary.

I have spent at least a few hours trying to figure out why this PC cannot get admin rights, and have run out of ideas. There is also an ex-navy system admin that has been unable to figure it out (though he is outdated in knowledge). Any advice on what to look at would be appreciated. I personally am a webmaster, and have very little server 03 knowledge, so any high-tech terms would prefer to be avoided :) - I can figure out whatever needs to be done though :)

Answer (score 0):

Are they a member of the Administrator group on the local machine?

Check [this](http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2010/01/how-to-use-group-policy-preferences-to-secure-local-administrator-groups/) for instructions on security, and being able to make people as admins of machines in a domain